# Azure PowerShell - Invoke-AzContainerInstanceCommand - The term 'processÂ' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

I am relatively new to Azure PowerShell so forgive any obvious issues.

I am trying to automate some commands on my ContainerInstances and I am using Runbook within Azure Automation but keep getting the following error:

```
Failed
The term 'processÂ' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. (The term 'processÂ' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.)
```

My script is as followed:

```
try
{
    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Connect-AzAccount -Identity
}
catch {
    Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
    throw $_.Exception
}

#Get-AzContainerInstanceUsage -Location eastus

Get-AzContainerGroup

Invoke-AzContainerInstanceCommand -Command "touch /tmp/foooo.txt" -ResourceGroupName DevApplication -ContainerGroupName foo-dev -ContainerName foo-dev-one
```

The command `Get-AzContainerGroup` works fine and returns data. So I can connect and interact with resources etc but I cannot run `Invoke-AzContainerInstanceCommand`

When I run `Invoke-AzContainerInstanceCommand` on my terminal (OSX) it works fine and created the tmp file. So I am a little stumped.

Comment: It looks like a character-encoding problem, but the word `process` appears nowhere else in your question.

Comment: Yeah, I think the `process` is coming from an installed module. I personally think it is an Azure issue.

Comment: I'd suggest using quotes around `foo-dev`, `foo-dev-one` etc. in order not to confuse Powershell to think it is a function or cmdlet. You probably have a ContainerGroupName or ContainerName called `process-something` and apart from the need of quoting, you have to retype the hyphen in your real code because it is now mis interpreted as EN-dash or something. Sanitizing real names in a question is fine, but not if this does not match the error message anymore.

Comment: @Theo thanks for that. I added the params to double quotes and rewrote everything by hand. still nothing. Thank for your help though.

Comment: @Theo interestingly if I choose the runtime at 7.1 (preview it works) so could be some weird quirks with Azure PowerShell

Comment: I am also encountering this issue using Az Powershell versions 9.3 and 10.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly for anyone reading this. If I use PowerShell Runbook with Runtime set to 7.1 (Preview) the script works.